# Spark 2.3.2 DAG creation utilises single CPU core and is slow

Tags: apache-spark

I have a large number of fairly complex transformations I am making on CSV data source files of between 500,000 and 2m rows. I see via the UI and htop that spark only uses 1 CPU and it runs at 100% as it builds the DAG up. Once it hits an action, all 48 cores are used at 100% (as expected).

The issue I have is the DAG creation takes 10s of minutes and the other 47 cores are idle. This happens in both local mode (master = local[*]) and on AWS EMR (master = yarn, client mode). Here is my command for local:

```
spark-submit --driver-memory=60g --driver-class-path <jar>  --class <class name> --conf spark.shuffle.partitions=48 --exclude-packages <exc. packages> --packages <packages>
```

Here is my spark-defaults.conf

```
spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold    -1
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -XX:+UseG1GC
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -XX:+UseG1GC
```

How can I make the DAG creation utilize more than one core ?

At one stage, I did hit bug SPARK-13346 that caused issues with DAG build up due to large lineage. I am doing copious checkpoint (and persists) to remove the lineage - and I still have v slow performance.